# dockerfile: vim (compiled python), vim-ipython, and ipython notebook

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, vim-ipython

I would like to build a Dockerfile in linux which
  1. compiles vim with python
  2. installs python stack (such as numpy, scipy, ipython, etc)
  3. creates ssl certificate for ipython-notebook, to view the notebooks on host machine

It seemed straightforward enough. But I have run into problems despite a variety of approaches, such as linking separate containers, using anaconda, as well as with a single unified image vs separate layers, or creating a `user` or running all as a root.

In order to run vim, simply installing to root, does not activate pathogen `bundle/vim-ipython`.  Creating a `user` allows `pathogen` bundles (ie nerdtree works) to install, but `:IPython` throws error.

`:IPython  failed
^-- failed '' not found` .

Ive tried the above with no layers/1 large Dockerfile, and with different layers for the python stack, vim, and the ipython notebook.

[Dockerfile](http://pastebin.com/qAK9grij)

What am I not seeing here ?
what does the `^-- failed '' not found` referring to?
Ive tried running the ipython notebook using `--no-browser &` and then running vim, or using running two shells on the same container... but cant get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [Dockerfile](http://pastebin.com/KnyXAXu7) for anyone trying to get vim-ipython working in Docker.

> > issues:
> >
> > 1. user/shared home needed to for vim, despite runtimepath in .vimrc to pathogen/bundle
> > 2. %connect_info >> required with containers

I am running in root, not sure why vim required `a USER` to install packages, but changing to `USER` would throw errors with `CMD`

--best